# C++ Graphics Update with Space Invaders

Tags: c++, windows, graphics

I am trying to run my game Space Invaders but I am encountering a graphics problem. To play the game you shoot the gun with the left click button, which triggers a new thread that takes the current X position of the bullet, draws the bullet, then sleeps and covers up the bullet with the background color. This continues in a loop to make the bullet move. I am having problems 'covering up' the bullet.

[image: The extra uncovered bullets are shown in red]

```
void bullet(int startpos1, int startpos2, HWND hwnd)
 {
int starty1 = 500;
int starty2 = 460;

while (starty2 > 0)
{
    starty1 = starty1 - 5;
    starty2 = starty2 - 5;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    SetDCPenColor(hdc, RGB(255, 255, 255));
    SetDCBrushColor(hdc, RGB(255, 255, 255));
    SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));
    SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(DC_PEN));
    Rectangle(hdc, startpos2, starty1, startpos1, starty2);

    Sleep(50);

    SetDCPenColor(hdc, RGB(0, 0, 0));
    SetDCBrushColor(hdc, RGB(0, 0, 0));
    SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));
    SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(DC_PEN));
    Rectangle(hdc, startpos2, starty1 , startpos1, starty2 );
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);


 }
}
```

`hdc` is a global variable for the handle for my window. You can find my code at http://pastebin.com/Jd3jmf8w.

Comment: Did you try the same code without any multithreading ? I am unsure that GDI is compatible with multithreading. If not, then you may need to add a mutex.

Comment: This application really needs multithreading to be effective, such as firing multiple bullets and moving simultaneously. I will give the mutex a shot.

Comment: @ZacheryUtt, the other option you have is to calculate what's needed in various threads which place their results in a queue (or some threadsafe container) then do the screen updating all on one thread. This might save you some hassles if the GUI library is not threadsafe.

Comment: Will the while loop not shut itself off if the condition is not true? If starty2 is less than 0 there is nothing else left to compute.

Comment: @ZacheryUtt, ah yeah I missed that. Disregard my earlier comment.

Comment: 1.I do not agree that multi threading is needed Invader games runs on old 8 bits HW without any multi threading so if it runs slow you most likely have some problem in your code 2. have you tried back buffering? it eliminates the need to compute/remember the clearing areas is much simpler completely removes flickering but is a bit slower (but now days HW can handle it with ease) 3. you should not access windows visual stuff from different then main window thread it causes whole bunch of problems not just visual ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calculate what's needed in various threads which place their results in a queue (or some threadsafe container) then do the screen updating all on one thread. This might save you some hassles if the GUI library is not threadsafe. –  shuttle87